# rspec test with fake date

Tags: ruby-on-rails, date, rspec, lambda

I try to fake the `Date.today` in order to test a scenario in my rails application:

```
before do
  Date.stub(:today).and_return("2010-10-01".to_date)
end
```

I have a scope (I'm using squeel gem) which is supposed to find future payments in my DB:

```
class Payment < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :future, -> { where{payment_date > Date.today} }
end
```

(I do it with a lambda because in the original code the scope uses a sifter, I posted here a simplified code.)

When I run the spec, it seems like the date is computed inside the lambda/sql and I get results for payments that are future compared to the real date (instead my fake 01/10/10) - can you confirm I'm right? you have a suggestion how I can test such a scenario with rspec?

Answer (score 2):

You should take a look at the TimeCop gem. I allows to freeze the date at a give time.

Here is the link
https://github.com/travisjeffery/timecop

Comment: This is precisely the problem that Timecop was created to solve.